# Why does my computer cap out on resources after 10+ hours of run time

Tags: memory, cpu, resources

So I am currently running an i5-8400 CPU with a 1060 3GB GPU with 16 GB of ram. I play Minecraft or code in java, and for both I use around 4-5GB of ram for each. But if I close out of all of those and leave my computer running overnight, i will come back with 100% CPU usage and 100% ram usage. I look at task manager, and nothing is using my ram and nothing is using my cpu. Also this happens when i turn it on in the morning and come back later, not just during the night.

Comment: I suggest running several deep antivirus scans using more than one well-known antivirus product, but at least with [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).

Comment: I have used Avira to check, and everything came back positive, granted, that was before I messed it up. I will try Malwarebytes, but i dont think its Malware. Thank you anyway!

Comment: If your malware scans came back clear it is more likely that one of the applications you left running has a memory leak. You should patch your software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edited]
Hmm a strange story indeed, Have you checked for programs that run in the background in the details tab of task manager(windows this should give you more information)? And also check in the startup tab of task manager. If it's not that it's probably your operating system, maybe something in your lock screen causes this, try and turn those settings on and off. And if that's not the case, I would indeed run some kind of malware scan as harrymc suggested.

[Update]
I found someone with a similar problem [here](https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/ram-usage-gradually-increasing-while-idle-how-do-i-fix-it/).
While being a old thread, it might indeed be caching of your operating system that is the problem.

Clear your trash can and your cookies just to make sure it's not something on a website you visited. Maybe try turn caching off in your operating system if that's a setting. If nothing works, I would actually make a backup and try reinstall my operating system depending on the urgency of the problem.

If it then keeps on going after a reinstalation, I would repost this on the forum of your operating system developers.

Comment: Well, the thing is that i have checked with Task Manager to see if anything is running in the background. Nothing. Also it couldn’t be my lock screen as its not on the lock screen. I will try and run an anti malware scan, but my antivirus gets messed up from restore points. Thanks for your help! I’ll reply with more information later.